# References in C

Tags: c++, c, reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing pointer argument by reference under C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825794/passing-pointer-argument-by-reference-under-c)

Are reference variables a C++ concept? Are they available in C? If available in C, why is my code giving a compilation error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int a = 10;
  int b = 20;
  int &c = a;
  int &d = b;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
bash-3.2$ gcc test.c
test.c: In function `main':
test.c:12: error: parse error before '&' token
```

Why?

Comment: You can format code as code by putting four spaces in front of every line. (I've done it for you here.)

Comment: Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825794/passing-pointer-argument-by-reference-under-c/1825813#1825813

Answer (score 11):

C does not have references as a type.  The '&' in C is used to get the address of a variable only.  It cannot be used the way you are trying to use it in C.

Answer (score 6):

1. It's a concept available on C++ (but not exclusively)
2. No, it is not available in standard C.
3. <strike>See 1 and 2.</strike> See *1 and *2.

Comment: Should point 3 be "See *1 and *2"? ;)

Answer (score 6):

You can't use this to declare variables:

```
int &c = a;
```

The operator & is used to get the memory address of a variable. So, you could write for example:

```
int a = 10;
int *c;
c = &a;
```

Comment: true in C, but C++ allows it.

Answer (score 4):

Pass by reference isn't available in C, use simple pointers instead.

Answer (score 2):

References are a C++ concept only. In C you are restricted to using only pointers.

Answer (score 2):

It's been awhile but it looks like you are trying to assign the address of c to the value of a.

Correction: value of a to the address of c. (Thanks Chinmay Kanchi for pointing that out.)

Comment: No, he's trying to assign the value of a to the address of c. Either way, it's downright illegal.

Answer (score 1):

No, reference is C++ only.